# Find the smallest positive prime divisor of ...

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

**Problem:**

> [image]

That's a problem I have found on the web. I didn't understand  the solution:
 Why??

**Given solution:**

> [image]

How all this sequence has been transformed into $$33-{\lfloor {33\over p}\rfloor} \mod p$$

Thank you

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

If $p\nmid a$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$. This is Fermat's
little theorem. Therefore $a^{(p-1)m}\equiv1\pmod p$. So, if $(p-1)\mid 60$
and $p\nmid a$ then $a^{60}\equiv1\pmod p$. This is true for $p\in\{ 2,3,5,7,11,13,31,61\}$. Of course $a^{60}\equiv1\pmod p$ if $p\nmid a$.

If $p\le 13$ then $\sum_{a=1}^N a^{60}\equiv t\pmod p$ where $t$ is the number
of non-multiples of $p$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$.

Comment: I don't understand how do you find 17. And what is the ⌊33/p⌋ mod p??

Comment: The set $\{2,3,5,7,11,13,31,61\}$ contains all primes $<17$. Also $33-\lfloor{33/p}\rfloor$ is the number of non-multiples of $p$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,33\}$.

Comment: But how can you verify that $17\mid \sum_{a=1}^N a^{60}$ by the simple fact that  NOT $(17-1)\mid 60$ ?? It also happens with 19, 23 and 29 but those aren't prime factors of that number. Or am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: @alienflow I don't follow your comment. Neither your question, nor my answer, make any reference to divisibility by $17$.

Comment: But the question is about the smallest prime divisor (which is 17 in this case). I wanted to know the condition by which you have found out that 17 is actually the answer. Is (17-1)|60 the ultimate condition by which you have determined that 17 is the smallest prime divisor?

Comment: But **your** question was about how $33-\lfloor\frac{33}p\rfloor$ was obtained for primes **less** than $17$.

Comment: My first question was in general about the solution (why) and then I asked for 33-floor(33/p) concretely