# Finding the smallest prime factor of $\sum_{a=1}^N a^{k}$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, prime-factorization

This question is linked to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903089/find-the-smallest-positive-prime-divisor-of), but I wanted a clearer explanation.

---

Suppose we have a huge number of that type with a huge $k$.

$$\sum_{a=1}^N a^{k} =1^{k}+2^{k}+3^{k}+...+N^{k},$$

and we want to find the smallest prime factor. We want to find the smallest $p$ for which

$$\sum_{a=1}^N a^{k} =1^{k}+2^{k}+3^{k}+...+N^{k}\equiv 0 \pmod p.$$

[image]

Let's review some facts about $a^{k}\pmod p$: by Fermat's Little Theorem $a^{k}\equiv 1\pmod p$ if $(p-1)\mid k∧p∤a$. Otherwise $a^{k}≢1\pmod p$ and in the particular case when $p|a⟹a^{k} \equiv 0\pmod p$. If the exponent is a multiple of $p-1$, the powers becomes equal to 1.

Okay, now it's here where I get stuck. How do I continue to find the smallest prime factor? Should I count each $a^{k} \pmod p$? I think that I am missing something but I can't nail it.

Comment: Possibly misleading use of the polymorphic $|$ to mean both "such as" and "divides" in cases where either interpretation lead to well formed statements.

Comment: Here I use it mainly to mean that it DIVIDES

Comment: Also as i do not know where this question comes from, i assume worst case it is dependent on reiman hypothesis? And you have to divide a whole bunch of times.

Comment: I would start by considering cases, either it is prime or not.

Comment: Also maybe related to euler product. Well seems to be it but only for negative $s$ and for finite sums.

Comment: It comes from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903089/find-the-smallest-positive-prime-divisor-of

Comment: Considering cases can be really tough if N is huge and, what $s$??

Comment: Factorization is hard. Secure communication depends on the difficulty of factorization. There's no reason to think that there's any easy way to find the smallest prime factor, or any prime factor, of that number, in general.